# Winforms element movement lag

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on my Course project and i need to make a Rythm game.

The issue im facing is in the note movment. Currently notes are represented by 5px tall buttons, that move down at 40 px a tick. I have a timer that moves every button in note list every tick and deletes them if they reached the border. Issue becomes apparent when there is more than 2 moving notes at the same time, time between every tick becomes longer the more notes there are on the screen.

Here is the code for note movment:

```html
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Button Note in AllNotes.ToList()){
                
                Note.Top -= 30;
          
                if (Note.Top < 0 || AllNotes.Count > 3)
                {
                    AllNotes.Remove(Note);
                    this.Controls.Remove(Note);
                }
            }
        }
```

Can such thing be fixed by turning on some feature like DoubleBuffering, or do i need to remake it completly in a different way?

One of the requirments is that it must be make in WinForms and not any advanced engine like Unity.

Comment: Do you mean that the time between consecutive `timer3_Tick` increases? How long is the timer interval and how long does the `timer3_Tick` method take to execute?

Comment: It indeed looks like time between each tick execution increses. Tick interval is set to 1 for smothest movement, thou I dont know exact time for execution, and will get back to you when i have that info.

Comment: "set to 1" - 1 millisecond?

Comment: Default Winforms timer appers to mesure in milliseconds,  after mesuring time for groups of notes, 1 note takes bewtween 10 and 14 ms per tick, 2 notes 22 to 26 ms and 3  notes 36 to 43 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there is a unit of work that we'll call "move notes" and you're doing this at set intervals. The tricky thing is that we really don't know how long it takes to move the notes. Obviously moving 10,000 notes will take longer than moving 10, and if it takes (hypothetically) a whole second to move them all and you're attempting to to this 10 times a second then things can get backed up and execute more and more slowly.

One thing you could try is a different kind of timer loop, basically:

1. Move all the notes, no matter how long it takes.
2. Wait for some time interval to expire.
3. Repeat

---

Here's how this could look in the MainForm class:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        _timerTask = Task.Run(() => execTimer(), _cts.Token);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => _cts.Cancel();
    }
    private Task _timerTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private void execTimer()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // This is on a worker task. Blocking here
            // isn't going to block the UI thread.
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested) break;

            // Execute some 'work' synchronously. This prevents
            // work from piling up if it can't be completed.
            TimerTick?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        }
    }
    internal static event EventHandler TimerTick;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

Your current code is iterating a list of Notes and instructing them to move one by one. Have you considered making the notes smart enough to move themselves? The way you would do this is to make a `Note` class that can respond to the timer events fired by the main form.

```
class Note : Button
{
    public Note(Point location)
    {
        Size = new Size(25, 25);    // Arbitrary for testing
        BackColor = Color.Black;
        Location = location;
        // Subscribe to the timer tick
        MainForm.TimerTick += onTimerTick;
    }
    private void onTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            // Execute the move
            Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y + 10); 

            // Detect whether the location has moved off of the
            // main form and if so have the Note remove itself.
            if(!Parent.ClientRectangle.Contains(Location))
            {
                MainForm.TimerTick -= onTimerTick;
                Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
            }               
        }));
    }
}
```

---

To make sure that the motion doesn't get bogged down I did a simple test where I'm adding a `Note` for every mouse click.

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    .
    .
    .
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        var button = new Note(e.Location)
        {
            Name = $"button{++_buttonIndex}",
        };
        Controls.Add(button);
        Text = $"{++_buttonCount} Active Notes";
    }
    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);
        if(e.Control is Note)
        {
            Text = $"{--_buttonCount} Active Notes";
        }
    }
    private int
        _buttonCount = 0,
        _buttonIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, i finaly got aound to implementing it in my project, however, as im yet to delve into Tasks i am not shure how to stop timer, to prevent "cant write to closed file" issues.

Comment: If you'd like to post that as a new question, I'd be happy to see if I can assist with that issue! I'm monitoring this thread so if you do make a new question please put a link to it in a comment here. Thx!