# Windows forms runs slowly when theres a background image

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I am making a simple breakout game with windows forms in visual studio. I have noticed the game runs badly when the game timer is set below 20 and when a background image is added it decreases the performance even move. The moving objects stutter and when 2 objects are moving at once both of them slow down.

I have tried multiple images and it seems the bigger the image the bigger the performance drop

Here is my code

```
// Variables
int playerSpeed;
int score;
bool moveLeft;
bool moveRight;
int deflection;
int ballBaseSpeed;
int ballXSpeed;
int ballYSpeed;
int difficulty = 1;

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void setupGame()
{
    playerSpeed = 7 * difficulty;
    score = 0;
    moveLeft = false;
    moveRight = false;
    deflection = 0;
    ballBaseSpeed = 5 * difficulty;
    ballXSpeed = ballBaseSpeed;
    ballYSpeed = ballBaseSpeed;
    gameTimer.Start();
}

private void gamerTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Player Move
    if (moveRight & player.Left < 784 - player.Width)
    {
        player.Left += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (moveLeft & player.Left > 0)
    {
        player.Left -= playerSpeed;
    }
    // Ball Collisions
    if (ball.Top < 0)
    {
        ballYSpeed *= -1;
        ball.Top = 0;
    } else if (ball.Top > 461 - ball.Height)
    {
        gameTimer.Stop();
    }
    if (ball.Left < 0) 
    {
        ballXSpeed *= -1;
        ball.Left = 0;
    } else if (ball.Left > 784 - ball.Width)
    {
        ballXSpeed *= -1;
        ball.Left = 784 - ball.Width;
    }
    if (ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(player.Bounds))
    {
        // Calculates how much extra speed to add depending on where the ball lands on the paddle
        deflection = ((((player.Left + (player.Width / 2) - ball.Width / 2) - ball.Left) * -1) / 10);
        // If ball is on right side and travelling left then the ball direction swaps
        if (deflection > 0 & ballXSpeed < 0) 
        {
            ballXSpeed *= -1;
        // If ball is on left side and travelling right then the ball direction swaps
        } else if (deflection < 0 & ballXSpeed > 0)
        {
            ballXSpeed *= -1;
        }
        ballYSpeed *= -1;
        // Resets ball speed to minimum and calculates the extra speed needed due to paddle position
        if (ballXSpeed > 0)
        {
            ballXSpeed = ballBaseSpeed + deflection;
        } else if (ballXSpeed < 0)
        {
            ballXSpeed = (ballBaseSpeed * -1) + deflection;
        }
    }
    // Ball Movement
    ball.Left += ballXSpeed;
    ball.Top -= ballYSpeed;

    // Blocks Collisions
    foreach(Control x in this.Controls)
    {
        if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "blocks")
        {
            if (ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds)) {
                this.Controls.Remove(x);
                ballYSpeed *= -1;
                score += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Display and updating text
    scoreLabel.Text = ("Score: " + score.ToString());

}

private void keyIsDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Player Controls
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        moveRight = true;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        moveLeft = true;
    }
}

private void keyIsUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Player Controls
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        moveRight = false;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        moveLeft = false;
    }
}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setupGame();
    startButton.Hide();
    easyButton.Hide();
    hardButton.Hide();
    startButton.Enabled = false;
    easyButton.Enabled = false;
    hardButton.Enabled = false;
}

private void hardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    difficulty = 2;
}

private void easyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    difficulty = 1;
}
```

Comment: How many PictureBoxes are in play here?  Winforms wasn't optimized for gaming speed.

Comment: Transparency effects get awfully expensive when the BackgroundImage has to be resized every time before it can be combined with a PictureBox.Image.  Stay ahead of it by resizing the image in an event handler for the Load event to be an exact fit for the form's ClientSize.  The pixel format of the images is quite important, Format32bppPArgb is ten times faster than the other ones.  Do fix the Controls.Remove() bug, that needs to be x.Dispose(), iterating backwards.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957222/5438626 it addresses a similar concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are still some parts missing in this question, since the performance problems most probably don't arise from the movement calculation, but from drawing of the game elements. However, I think I can make an educated guess what is going on here.

From what I see, it seems you are using picture boxes for the blocks, and probably for the ball as well. That's the problem - Winforms isn't optimized for drawing a lot of overlapping controls in one form, especially not when the controls change their position. With a background image, you get a lot of overlapping, and any repositioning of the ball will probably cause a redrawing of all controls - and that's quite slow.

For a game like this, I would recommend not to (ab)use picture boxes or other standard controls. Better implement your own drawing of the elements in the `OnPaint` event of the form or a panel which belongs to the form. That gives you full control about what needs to be redrawn and what not, and when you don't introduce any serious error there, then this should solve your performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I am using picture boxes for everything except the background. I started learning this yesterday so Im very very new to it. I will try using my own drawings in the onpaint event like you said.

Comment: Ive started using the paint event to draw my images instead now. That fixed the slowdown, but the drawigns seem to move a bit jittery. They are fine but it doesnt feel very good.

Comment: @Britishblue: you need to learn about double buffering. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12870/Don-t-Flicker-Double-Buffer) I found something which looks like a good start.