# Controls.Add doesn't draw an image

Tags: c#, winforms

For my coursework I need to create a game, something like a piano.  I decided to draw the interface through `Controls.Add`, but in the case of a static interface everything works, but if I try to create falling notes through an `async` function, then they are not drawn.  I read the documentation, there are no obvious errors in my code, MessageBox appears.  Please point out the error. Here the code:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace osu_2
{ 

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Note> songNotes;
        private List<TouchArea> touchAreas;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeTouchAreas();
            InitializeSongPattern();


            string backgroundPath = "D:\\VS Projects\\osu_2\\Resources\\background.png";
            Bitmap background = new Bitmap(backgroundPath);
            BackgroundImage = background;

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            UpdateStyles();

            Task.Run(() => CreateAndDropNotes());
        }

        private void InitializeTouchAreas()
        {
            touchAreas = new List<TouchArea>();
            int AreaCount = 4;
            int AreaWidth = 100;
            int AreaHeight = 100;
            int AreaX = 1300;

            string AreaImagePath = "D:\\VS Projects\\osu_2\\Resources\\area.png";
            Keys[] AreaKeys = { Keys.A, Keys.S, Keys.D, Keys.F };

            for (int i = 0; i < AreaCount; i++)
            {
                TouchArea TouchArea = new TouchArea();
                TouchArea.Tag = AreaKeys[i];
                TouchArea.Image = Image.FromFile(AreaImagePath);
                TouchArea.BackColor = Color.Black;
                TouchArea.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                TouchArea.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                TouchArea.Size = new Size(AreaWidth, AreaHeight);
                TouchArea.Location = new Point(AreaX, 800);
                AreaX += TouchArea.Width + 30;

                touchAreas.Add(TouchArea);
                Controls.Add(TouchArea);
            }
           
        }

        private void InitializeSongPattern()
        {
            songNotes = new List<Note>
            {
                new Note{ Time = 2000, Key = Keys.A},
                new Note{ Time = 3000, Key = Keys.S}
            };
        }

        private PictureBox DrawNotes(TouchArea TimeArea, Note notekey)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter");
            PictureBox notebox = new PictureBox();
            notebox.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\VS Projects\\osu_2\\Resources\\note2.png");
            notebox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
            notebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            notebox.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            notebox.Location = new Point(TimeArea.Location.X, TimeArea.Location.Y - 500);
            notebox.Tag = notekey.Key;

            Controls.Add(notebox);

            return notebox;
        }

        private async Task CreateAndDropNotes()
        {
            foreach (var Note in songNotes)
            {
                await Task.Delay(Note.Time);

                TouchArea TimeArea = null;

                foreach (var area in touchAreas)
                {
                    if ((Keys)area.Tag == Note.Key)
                    {
                        TimeArea = area;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (TimeArea != null)
                {   
                    PictureBox notebox = new PictureBox();

                    notebox = DrawNotes(TimeArea, Note);

                    while (notebox.Location.Y < TimeArea.Location.Y)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(20);
                        notebox.Location = new Point(notebox.Location.X, notebox.Location.Y + 5);
                    }

                    Controls.Remove(notebox);
                }


            }
        }

    

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
                this.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Note
    {
        public int Time {  get; set; }
        public Keys Key { get; set; }
    }

    public class TouchArea : PictureBox
    {
        public TouchArea()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I tried putting notes into an array and drawing them from the array, I tried rendering them in a separate function (in the code), also ask GPT,but still haven't found the error

Comment: ...why does seemingly no-one ever rename their `Form1` to something more meaningful?

Comment: While not a duplicate question, you may benefit from looking as this thread. [Winforms element movement lag:I am currently working on my Course project and i need to make a Rythm game.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74926576/5438626)

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that `Task.Run` will run `CreateAndDropNotes`on a background thread, and you are not allowed to update the UI from a background thread. This is an very important rule: *only do updates from the UI thread!*

What you should do is use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) to raise an events at some regular interval. This will give you a chance to update the UI and do any animations you want to. A [periodic timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-8.0) *might* be an alternative, but I would probably recommend the winforms timer.

Also note that windows by default uses about 16ms resolution for timers, keep this in mind when doing any kind of animations. You might also want to use a [stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-8.0) to accurately measure time between updates, stopwatch should have a precision of at least 100ns. This should help ensure animations keep a constant tempo even if update frequency vary a bit.

You might also consider doing [custom drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/custom-painting-drawing?view=netdesktop-8.0) instead of using picture boxes. This might help with performance for something that is constantly updating like a game.

Comment: Thx a lot, helped solve my problem)